# How to sort XML with XSLT and Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I need to sort an XML file on an element's attribute.
The file is similar to this

```
<employees>
<employee firstname="Mary" lastname="Poppins" age="30" hobby="Flying"/>
<employee firstname="Captain" lastname="Hook" age="40" hobby="Crocodile hunting"/>
<employee firstname="Thomas" lastname="Tankengine" age="102" hobby="Steam trains"/>
<employee firstname="Ant" lastname="Man" age="37" hobby="hero"/>
<employee firstname="Peter" lastname="Pan" age="13" hobby="Flying"/>
```

And I need to sort the employees on lastname so that the xml looks like this

```
<employees>
  <employee firstname="Captain" lastname="Hook" age="40" hobby="Crocodile hunting" />
  <employee firstname="Ant" lastname="Man" age="37" hobby="hero" />
  <employee firstname="Peter" lastname="Pan" age="13" hobby="Flying" />
  <employee firstname="Mary" lastname="Poppins" age="30" hobby="Flying" />
  <employee firstname="Thomas" lastname="Tankengine" age="102" hobby="Steam trains" />
</employees>
```

I've tried all sorts of examples and looked over stackoverflow but I am clearly missing something fundamental.

This is my latest attempt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <xsl:apply-templates select = "employee"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="employee">
<xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort select="@lastname" order="ascending"/>"
</xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why you need it sorted?

Comment: Well, look for `xsl:sort` in XSLT 1, for `xsl:perform-sort` in XSLT 2.0 and later or for the simple XPath 3.1 `sort` function.

Comment: Jens - The data originates from SQL in the wrong sequence. The XML is to be sent to a control that does not have sort capability so I need to get it into the correct sequence before passing it on.

Comment: *"I've tried all sorts of examples*" Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Martin - I have tried all these and have been unable to get the result I need. I'd hoped for a simple working example I can build on

Comment: @Andy L You'll find examples in any XSLT textbook or online tutorial. We don't want to write a tutorial just for you any more than we want to write the code just for you. Tell us what you tried and we will quickly see where your misunderstanding lies. Most commonly with beginners, the mistake is to get the context for your path expressions wrong; if we can see that's what you've done, then we can explain it to you.

Comment: And another point here: if you just copy examples, you won't understand WHY it works, which means you will get it wrong when you try to adapt it to your needs. You need to understand the concepts, not just copy and paste example code.

Comment: @MichaelKay - thanks for the feedback - I've added my attempts to the question

Comment: Great. Your mistake was that the template with `match="employee"` is only processing a single employee, and sorting one employee isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The right template would be

```
  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
        <xsl:sort select="@lastname"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

you would then need to make sure there is the identity transformation set up, with the current version 3.0 of XSLT that would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
        <xsl:sort select="@lastname"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I could only get  <employees></employees> as an output using this method

Comment: @AndyL, the complete code I posted is XSLT 3 as XSLT 3 is the current version of XSLT since 2017; to use it you can use e.g. SaxonJS 2 for JavaScript or Node.js or Saxon Java 11 or 12 for Java or SaxonC 12 for C/C++/Python/PHP. If you insist to live in the XSLT 1.0 world from 1999, it is your choice, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is sort, leaving everything else as is, you could do simply (in XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="employee">
            <xsl:sort select="@lastname"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or in XSLT 2.0 and higher:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/employees">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="employee">
            <xsl:sort select="@lastname"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The first option worked. The second one gave me an error saying perform sort couldn't be inside a xsl:copy - so I am gong to use your first option - thanks

Comment: That means you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. You can verify this by looking at `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>`. When you ask about XSLT, it is crucial to know which version you can use.